# How to get the distance of the object and How to use camera calibration matrix correctly?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I succesfully calibrate my camera using opencv. The camera lens i am using. 
https://www.baslerweb.com/en/products/vision-components/lenses/basler-lens-c125-0418-5m-f1-8-f4mm/

The internal and external camera parameter is given below.

```
cv::Mat cameraMatrix(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(0) = 1782.80;//fx //432.2 in mm
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(1) = 0;
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(2) = 3.0587694283633488e+002;//cx
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(3) = 0;
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(4) = 1782.80;//fy
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(5) = 3.0535864258476721e+002;//cy
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(6) = 0;
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(7) = 0;
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(8) = 1;


    cv::Mat disCoeffs(1, 5, cv::DataType<double>::type);
    disCoeffs.at<double>(0) = -8.1752937039996709e-001;//k1
    disCoeffs.at<double>(1) = -2.5660653367749450e+001;//k2
    disCoeffs.at<double>(2) = -1.5556922931812768e-002;//p1
    disCoeffs.at<double>(3) = -4.4021541217208054e-002;//p2
    disCoeffs.at<double>(4) = 1.5042036073609015e+002;//k3
```

I know this formula is used to calculate the distance of the object. But i am very confuse how to proper use it.

[image]

Resolution of my camera is 640x480.

focal length = 1782.80 (px) do not know how to correctly convert to mm

i know focal length is distance from sensor to image plane. So what actually this value represent? Pixel is just a unit represent dot on screen.

Object i am using is circle. 
radius = 22. (width and height 44*44)
circle center point: 300,300 (x,y)

sensor height do not know how to get?

Where do i use principle points?

How i get distance from camera to object? How do get real world coordinate of the circle?

I know its too much to ask. I try one month. Did not find any proper solution.

i use function solvePnP to get the camera translation and rotation matrix. But i have problem how to calculate object point?

Comment: According to the website you posted, the focal length is 4.0mm. Beyond that, you will just need the height of your sensor. When talking about your image, you need to speak in screen coordinates, not model or world coordinates.

Comment: how do i get height of sensor? so why do i need camera matrix？i know image cooedinate i need to get world coordinate?

Comment: You're using a physical camera to take a picture, right? The height of your camera relative to your subject changes the way the subject appears. Consider a top view versus a frontal view. The distance of the subject will determine how many 'pixels' of the sensor are affected by the subject (aka how many sensor pixels are hit by light coming from the subject). This directly corresponds to how many pixels the subject takes up in the image output from the camera. You can then back calculate to determine distance, if you know the real height of the object.

Comment: yes i am using camera in real time. how to caluclate sensor height? i do not understand what you say.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_distortion_(photography)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_sensor_format sensor size 1/2.5” 5.76mmx4.29mm widthxheight so distance object(mm)＝4mmx65mmx480px/44px x 4.29mm but real distance from camera to object around 88cm

Comment: How tall is the actual object?

Comment: object is circle. real world size is 6.5cm.

Comment: Size, meaning diameter? What is the height of the center of the lens of camera, relative to the center of the circle?

Comment: yes. sir. if you have skype if you can give i can express more better please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150367/discussion-between-vincent-and-muhammad-raza).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `cx` and `cy` seems to be wrong because they should be half the resolution: `640/2` & `480/2`. 
`fx` and `fy` are in pixel unit you get from calibration process. To convert them to `mm` use that formula:

```
pixels width = (image width in pixels) * (focal length in mm) / (CCD width in mm)

pixels height = (image height in pixels) * (focal length in mm) / (CCD height in mm)
```

When you calibrate your camera, you use those formulas to make sure you've the right values. For me `cx` and `cy` are wrong because they represent the center of the image (they shouldn't be equal unless your image is square which is not the case). For `fx` and `fy` I can't tell because I don't know the CCD of your camera. They can be equal if the CCD is square.

Don't change those parameters manually but let the your calibration software compute them.

***Now you've those parameters, how you compute the distance?***

The formula you presented is not useful in a sense that if you can measure the real height, you usually can measure the distance (at least in your case).. so why using a camera!?

So to compute the distance in real world, you need two more things: The extrinsic parameters (Your `cameraMatrix` matrix is the intrinsic parameters) and at least four points (the more points the better) in real world coordinates.
Once you have those things, you can use `solvePnP` function to find the pose of an object. The pose represents the translation and rotation with respect to the camera frame.

```
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp
```

This is a piece of code can help to do that:

```
//Four points in real world with `x,y and z` coordinates
vector<Point3f> vec3d;
vec3d.push_back(Point3f(0, 0, 0));
vec3d.push_back(Point3f(0, 211, 0));
vec3d.push_back(Point3f(295, 211, 0));
vec3d.push_back(Point3f(295, 0, 0));
```

The `z=0` because your real points are in a plane.

```
//The same four points but in your image plan, therefore there is no z and they're in pixel unit
vector<Point2f> vec2d;
vec2d.push_back(Point2f(532, 412)); //(y,x)
vec2d.push_back(Point2f(583, 594));
vec2d.push_back(Point2f(927, 535));
vec2d.push_back(Point2f(817, 364));

//The pose of the object: rvec is your rotation vector, tvec is your translation vector
cv::Mat rvec, tvec;
solvePnP(vec3d, vec2d, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec);
```

Finally, you can compute the real distance from the `tvec` as euclidean distance: `d=std::sqrt(tx*tx+ty*ty+tz*tz)`.

***Your questions:***

*sensor height do not know how to get?*

Look for your camera specification in the internet or in the manual book and you'll find it.

*Where do i use principle points?*

They're your intrinsic parameters. You're not gonna use them separately.

*How i get distance from camera to object? How do get real world coordinate of the circle?*

I explained that above. You need four points and with a circle you have only one which not enough to compute the pose.

*But i have problem how to calculate object point?*

objectPoints in solvePnP are your real world coordinates. For example, a chessboard has corners in which we know the exact position in mm of each one with respect to a world frame that you choose in the chessboard. It can be in the left top corner or something like that and z=0 because the chessboard is printed in a paper just like your circle!

**EDIT:**

You can find more specifications in the manual page 13 [here](http://www.toshiba-teli.co.jp/en/products/industrial/files/bg_bwe.pdf). It is said `7.4 x 7.4µm`:

```
f (mm)=f(pixel) x pixel_size(mm) => f (mm) = 1782.80x7.2e-6 = 12.83616 (mm)
```

Which is not 4mm!! then you need to do the calibration again, something is wrong!

3D points:
    vector vec3d;
`vec3d` is where you gonna store your 3D coordinates point. I gave you an example for the first point which the origin:

```
vec3d.push_back(Point3f(0, 0, 0)); //y,x,z
```

**EDIT3**

If you take a pattern like this

[image]

Then choose for example the circle in top left or right corner and it will have a coordinate of `(0,0,0)`, that the origin. After that the circle next to it is your second point and it will have `(x,0,0)` `x` is the distance in (mm) between the two circles.. You do the same for four points in your pattern. You can choose any pattern you want as long as you can detect it in your image and retrieve their coordinates in pixel. 
If you still don't understand, I advise you take a course in `projective geometry` and `camera models`.. so as you can understand what every parameter means.

Comment: Sir, thank you very much for your explanation. How you guess object points(vec3d)? CCD is the size of sensor?

Comment: And i am using camera toshiba teli bg030 i try to find CCD on internet but i cannot they just told CCD is square grid. https://www.avsupply.com/ITM/25466/bg030.html

Comment: Sir, i still do not understand how you get this point vec3d.push_back(Point3f(295, 211, 0));?

Comment: @MuhammadRaza look at EDIT3

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by But the world coordinate will change. Sorry I can't!  Learn from online course there're nice materials there, and if you need something just ask here or in answers.opencv.org

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150419/discussion-between-muhammad-raza-and-ja-cpp).

Comment: object is continuously moving. World Coordinate not remain the same.